# Pip freeze for local package

Tags: python, git, heroku, pip

I have an application, hedgehog (https://github.com/qfq8wf77qwf8/hedgehog-test) which I am deploying on heroku. This is the file structure:

```
hedgehog/
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── hedgehog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── app.db
│   ├── simple_page
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── models.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── hedgehog.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Some notes about my setup:

- I have setup.py which installs hedgehog locally. This allows all my files to access this app via import hedgehog
- I have requirements.txt because this is what Heroku recommends.
- Setup.py is basically a tool for me to package this directory as an application to be installed locally.

Currently, I install the `hedgehog` app locally via `pip install -e .`
This works fine - I can run my app using `flask run` and `heroku local`. I am also able to deploy this application on heroku.

My only problem is that when I do a pip freeze, I realize that my local application is shown as:

`-e git+git@github.com:qfq8wf77qwf8/hedgehog-test.git@12a6c0a1bf00b76c6a18e15d295fde6b70814fbd#egg=hedgehog`

If I leave this in my requirements.txt, my deployment will fail with the following messages:

```
remote:        Obtaining hedgehog from git+https://git.heroku.com/hedgehog.git@101439e90d0681e4952bd94ff7224d16e92d1b45#egg=hedgehog (from -r /tmp/build_fb9c8c5a426fa15f54b4e074abe57c25/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Cloning https://git.heroku.com/hedgehog.git (to 101439e90d0681e4952bd94ff7224d16e92d1b45) to /app/.heroku/src/hedgehog
remote:        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': No such device or address
remote:        Command "git clone -q https://git.heroku.com/hedgehog.git /app/.heroku/src/hedgehog" failed with error code 128 in None
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I am getting around this issue by manually changing that `-e git+git@github.com:qfq8wf77qwf8/hedgehog-test.git@12a6c0a1bf00b76c6a18e15d295fde6b70814fbd#egg=hedgehog`
to `e .` in my requirements.txt.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi Sparrowcide, did you ever figure this out? Running into same issue and would like `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to reference my local package rather than pointing to git.

Comment: Interested as well, facing the same problem